# Python separate sin waves Fourier Transform

Tags: python, trigonometry, fourier-descriptors

I'm currently trying to make a sin wave separator, at [replit.com](https://replit.com/@codeitfast/CelebratedTrustyString#main.py). However, I am running it, and the bottom graph is off. There should be on spike, but there are multiple in the area. It is using the function e ^ (-2pi * i * frequency * the height of the sin wave). Can anyone help me? The math I am basing it off of is [this video](https://youtu.be/spUNpyF58BY?t=974). Thank you!

```py
for i in range(180):
  height.append(cos(2 * i * const))
center = (0 + 0j)

centers = []
centers2 = []
centers3 = []

for a in range(180):
  f = a * const
  center = (0 + 0j)
  for a, i in enumerate(height):
    center += -i * e**(-2 * pi * 1j * f * a)
    #maybe fix equation? It looks off...
  center *= 1/(a)
  centers3.append(sqrt(center.real ** 2 + center.imag **2))
  centers.append(center.real)
  centers2.append(center.imag)
```

[image: example]

Comment: Please put the relevant code (a [mcve]) and the plot _in the question_

Comment: Part of this comes from the edges.  The Fourier transform assumes an infinite signal.  Your signal has sharp edges, and that causes aliasing, especially when your sample is so short.

Comment: @TimRoberts is there a way to fix that?

Comment: That's what "windowing" is for.  You attenuate the edges slightly -- basically, fading in and fading out.  You might look at the "Hann window".  You also might try running through multiple cycles.

Comment: You fix aliasing by applying a windowing function to the input, but as @TimRoberts says your sample is too short for that to be effective.

Comment: @MarkRansom I made the sin wave longer - 10 times longer. However, it still doesn't work.

Comment: It's not even windowing, the DFT equation you used is just wrong.

Comment: @MarkRansom It may be that I accidently had `for a in range(): for a in range`, inside each other.

Answer (score 0):

The thing in the exponential has a factor of 2 pi too much in it. So you could say that `f` is a factor of 2 pi too high, or that the factor of 2 pi does belong in `f` but then it shouldn't be repeated in the exponential, either way it's in there twice while it should be in there once.

Changed code, plus minor other edits:

```
from math import cos, pi, e, sqrt, atan2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

const = 2 * pi/180
height = []
for i in range(180):
  height.append(cos(2 * i * const))

amplitudes = []
phases = []

print(90 / 180, 90 * const)

for a in range(180):
  f = a / 180
  center = (0 + 0j)
  for index, sample in enumerate(height):
    center += sample * e**(-2 * pi * 1j * f * index)
    # fixed equation
  amplitudes.append(sqrt(center.real ** 2 + center.imag **2))
  phases.append(atan2(center.imag, center.real))

x = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 180)
y = height

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2,2)
ax[0,0].plot(x, y)
ax[1,0].plot(x, amplitudes)
ax[1,1].plot(x, phases, 'orange')
#ax[0,1].plot(x, centers3, 'orange')
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: plots]

Comment: Why does a not multiply 2pi? It was to convert to radians from degrees...

Comment: I tried to do `cos(2 * i * const) + cos(.5 * i * const)`, but it looks off, like a bezier between (0, 125) and (pi, 125).

Comment: @Codeitfast you can multiply by 2 pi there, but then the 2 pi from inside the exponential has to be removed. The usual Discrete Fourier Transform formula does not take the "index" input in radians, but in raw index (from 0 to N), and then it divides by N and multiplies by 2 pi to, well, turn it into radians after all. It doesn't really matter where that occurs, but applying the conversion twice is no good. BTW your new signal is not periodic, so you should apply a suitable window function to it.